# Want to Know about 5.1 sound system

Tags: 5.1, problem

Hi There,

My question is just critical. Acutally 5.1 Dvd player delivers Bass effect from Subwoofer outlet as well as front right and front left outlet. But my 5.1 receiver accepts the Bass effect from Subwoofer outlet only. It doesnt accepts the Bass effect  from front right and front left. Due to this there is no real 5.1 surround effect from my receiver. What i need is my 5.1 receiver should accept both Subwoofer Bass and front right left Bass. And it should deliver these Bass effects from the Subwoofer. So can any one tell the solution for my problem.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Read up on http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bass_management

Answer (score 1):

Most home entertainment receivers allow for Bass Management by setting the 5 monitors to ' *small* ' in the set-up menu - thus sending their low end (generally crossed over @ 80-120Htz) to the sub.

As *georgi.m* suggested: it would be good to read up on bass management theory to fully grasp what's going on here and how it affects your playback monitoring...

happy listening!
r

- this generally, only works for the *5.1 inputs* on your receiver - not the stereo inputs